# How does Chebyshev approximation of spectral convolution work?

Tags: papers, geometric-deep-learning, graph-neural-networks, spectral-analysis

I was reading the following paper: [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02907.pdf). In it, it talks about spectral graph convolutions and says:

> We consider spectral convolutions on graphs defined as the
> multiplication of a signal $x \in R^N$ (a scalar for every node)
> with a filter $g_{\theta}$ $=$ $\text{diag}  (\theta)$ parameterized
> by $\theta \in R^{N}$ in the Fourier domain, i.e.: $ g_{\theta} * x = U g_{\theta} U^Tx $. We can understand $ g_{\theta}$ as a function of the eigenvalues of $L$, i.e.  $g_{\theta}(\Lambda)$

So far, it makes sense. $U^T x$ is the graph Fourier transform of the signal $x$, then we multiply by $ g_{\theta}$ in the Fourier domain as: $FT(f * g) = F(\omega)G(\omega)$. Then we have the multiplication by $U$ in the front to represent the inverse (graph) Fourier transform.

Then the paper lists some reasons why using the above convolution equation may not be practical in reality:

- Evaluating the above equation is computationally expensive; multiplying with eigenvector matrix $U$ is $O(N^2)$
- Computing eigendecomposition of $L$ may be too expensive for an arbitrarily large graph
- etc.

and then the paper says:

> To circumvent this problem, it was suggested in Hammond et al. (2011)
> that $g_{\theta}(\Lambda)$ can be well-approximated by a truncated
> expansion in terms of Chebyshev polynomials $T_k (x)$ up to
> $K^{\text{th}}$ order: $$ g_{\theta '}(\Lambda) \approx \sum_{k =
> > 0}^{K} \theta_k ' T_k(\tilde{\Lambda}) $$
>
> with a rescaled $\tilde{\Lambda} = \frac{2}{\lambda_{\text{max}}}\Lambda − I_N$. $\lambda_{\text{max}}$
> denotes the largest eigenvalue of $L$. $\theta ′ \in R^K$ is now a
> vector of Chebyshev coefficients. The Chebyshev polynomials are
> recursively defined as $T_k(x) = 2xT_{k−1}(x) − T_{k−2}(x)$, with
> $T_0(x) = 1$ and $T_1(x) = x$. The reader is referred to Hammond et al. (2011) for an in-depth discussion of this approximation. Going
> back to our definition of a convolution of a signal $x$ with a filter
> $g_{\theta '}$, we now have: $$ g_{\theta '} * x \approx \sum_{k=0}^{K} \theta_k ′ T_k (\tilde{L}) x$$ with $\tilde{L} = \frac{2}{\lambda_{\text{max}}}L − I_N$ ; as can easily be verified by
> noticing that $(U \Lambda U^T)^k = U \Lambda^k U^T $

**Question:** What happened to the terms $U^T$ and $U$ which take the (graph) Fourier transform and invert it respectively?

**Attempt:** Does it have something to do with what is mentioned in the last line about noticing that $(U \Lambda U^T)^k = U \Lambda^k U^T $? I might guess that we use that because a k-th order Chebyshev polynomial will have $\Lambda ^k$ (and lower powers) present in the equation and thus the $U^T$ and $U$ mean that we can write the convolution equation in terms of the Laplacian matrix $L$

Comment: I can't understand the equation you pasted from the given paper. Can you please phase this question in your own words and use latex to write equations?

Comment: Hi @SwaksharDeb - the equations were written in Latex. Have fixed the few areas where the '>' character made it into the equations (meant for the block quote). The question can be summarized as: how did the Chebyshev function of $\tilde{\Lambda}$  into a function of L